# ImageMagick - deleting landscape images and crop/resize

Tags: imagemagick

I have a bunch of images (just over 10,000) which I need to perform two tasks to in order to fill up a digital photo frame with photos that are the right dimensions. Any help would be appreciated.

**Task 1:** Delete any photos that are portrait and leave only landscape.

**Task 2:** Resize and crop remaining images to 800 x 460.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *.jpg;
    do
    type=$(identify -format '%[exif:orientation]' $i)
    case $type in
    1)
    convert  $i     -resize 800x460^ \
          -gravity center -extent 840x460  $i_resized.jpg;;
    6)
    rm $i;;
    8)
    convert  $i     -resize 800x460^ \
          -gravity center -extent 840x460  $i_resized.jpg;;
esac
done
```

For more information on cropping and resizing with ImageMagick see

[ImageMagick v6 Examples -- 
 Resize or Scaling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/)